# Identify internal APIs used through reflection

Tags: java, reflection, jdeps

I'm working on a legacy codebase, which was originally written in JDK 1.1.6. As a result there are a number of instances where **internal JDK APIs** are being used, especially in the RMI & Socket programming area.

I need to identify and create a list of these internal APIs used throughout my codebase.

I understand `jdeps -jdkinternals` can solve my purpose, and yes this command is helping me out to far an extent

Unfortunately, in places where the ***internal APIs are being used through reflection*** this approach isn't working for me.

Is there any (efficient) way other than the brute-force text search, that I can use in this scenario?

Comment: I guess you're looking for something similar to the runtime option, [`--illegal-access`](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/261#Relaxed-strong-encapsulation), isn't it?

Comment: @nullpointer Not really; that would be among my next set of actions :)
Right now I need to have a list of changes that needs to be made in the codebase and some way to identify reflective use of Internal JDK APIs is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Well, I meant that `jdeps` already lets you know the API changes required in your application while the `--illegal-access` could help to identify reflective use in the code. A mix of both of these sounds like your requirement.